# What is the meaning of a cancelled publication in conference?

Tags: paper

In this [this link](http://www.sigir.org/sigir2012/tutorials.php), I see a cancelled publication (there is a horizontal line on its name):
Methods for Mining and Summarizing Text Conversations. What does it mean?

I would like to find this article. what should I do? It means that it has been moved to some other page or something else?

Comment: Have you considered asking the organizers?

Comment: This question is not about writing. Additionally, the question is answered at the very top of the web page in question.

Comment: @NeilFein Thanks for your comment. I didn't notice those explaining lines.

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly explained at the top of the page:

> The tutorials below that have strike-through font have been cancelled due to insufficient enrollment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't notice those lines.

Answer (score -1):

This means that the publication was removed completely. This is most likely because of an issue with  its content.